# asp.net MVC rendering partial views from another area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, view, c#-3.0, partial-views

My layout of areas is such:

Warehouse/

ClientProcesses/

SupplierProcess/

Inside "Warehouse/" - I have a partial view called "summaryUC", I want to access this from inside the view (aspx file) from "ClientProcess area" or "SupplierProcess area" how can i do that?

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("SummaryUC", Model.Summary); %>

<% Html.RenderPartial("~Warehouse/Views/Shared/SummaryUC", Model.Summary); %> ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi what you can do is put the partial view to location that is accesible everywhere.
so if you have partial view shared between areas, put the partial view into root/views/shared

this will ensure that they will be always found.